# why does my ipad not sort series properly

Tags: ipad

I have several tv series on my ipad mini running ios 7.1.2 and itunes is on windows 8, now my ipad has started to sort the seasons so that a few episodes are under 1 season tab and the rest of the season is under another which is very annoying as for example it shows me having 2 tabs for the 1st season of something. I have tried using itunes to change it but cant see how too and I deleted and re-downloaded all the series I'm having problems with but nothing has worked, please help me sort this

Comment: meta-data is probably wrong. Try bulk-editing all the data except the individual episode title & resync. Did this stuff come from Apple or 'elsewhere'? Also, why still iOS 7?

Comment: I've just updated and it hasn't fixed anything and everything was bought from itunes, all meta data is correct

Answer (score 1):

iFlicks 2 is a great app to manage video files in iTunes:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iflicks-2/id731062389?mt=12

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to edit meta data is via iTunes (on the computer):

- Open "Information" Window for an episode
- Set as TV Show

[image]

- Set Name, Season and Episode number

[image]

Depending on the kind of video *before* switching to TV Show you may need to close and reopen the window before the third steps to have the fields appear.

Comment: my itunes doesn't look like that or let me edit data :/

Comment: I've got it like that but there's nothing wrong with the meta data, everything is numbered and named correctly